# Dynamically create callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 10s of callback methods, they are all in the form of:

```
xCallback = (value) => {
    this.setState({x: value}, () => {
        this.update();
    });
};

yCallback = (value) => {
    this.setState({y: value}, () => {
        this.update();
    });
};
...
```

I pass these methods to child components as callbacks(3rd party components that I cannot modify):

```
<ChildComponent ... callback={this.xCallback}/>
```

Is there a way to shorten this code and get rid of duplicate code?

Comment: something like `const gen = n => v => { this.setState({[n]: v}, () => { this.update(); });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accept an aditional `parameter` which is the `key` to be updated. Since you can't change the signature of the function passed to your child component you can use `currying` to return a dynamic callback with a fixed signature

```
const generateCb = key => value => this.setState({ [key] : value }, () => {})

return <Child callback={generateCb('x')}
```

Where `generateCb('x')` will evaluate to

```
value => this.setState({ 'x' : value }, () =>{})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set second parameter as key

```
cCallback = (value, key) => {
    this.setState({[key]: value}, () => {
        this.update();
    });
};
```

Comment: this would not work because I cannot add extra arguments to callback, child component calls it with single argument

Comment: This doesn't work. He explicitly said that he can't change the signature of the callback provided to `Child`